# How to create custom java library and call its function inside Android App

Tags: java, android, jar

I am new to java and android development and I want to create my own java library (JAR files) and I want to call this jar lib function inside android app code base.

Although there are numerous online tutorials available which demonstrate how to do this I couldnt find one for a newbee person like me.

The resources available on the internet, assume that a person should be hands on java and android platform. This is not the case with me.

I have just started learning it and I want to create a java library and call its function into an Android App.

So to achieve this, below are the steps I have performed.

**Step 1 :** Created a sample program "Addition of 2 numbers" so this is what I have written.

```
 package MyPackage;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

 public class MyAddition {      
    public static int addition(int a, int b){
       return (a+b);
    }
 }
```

Saved it as MyAddition.java .Compiled and created its  class file MyAddition.class inside folder [folder_path]..../mylib/MyPackage/

**Steps 2 :** Created its JAR files using following command

```
   jar -cf mylib.jar [folder_path]../mylib
```

**Steps 3 :**

Now I have installed Android Studio in order to create my android app code base where I want to call this JAR lib function.

In Android Studio, I have created a new project using its predefined "bottom Navigation activity"  as "My Application" so the whole project is set up by the Android Studio. Here is a screenshot for the whole setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 4 :** : I have my complete application set up which looks like this.

[image]

**Step 5 :** : Now I want to integrate my JAR file which I've created earlier into this app. So to achieve this I've added the jar lib "mylib.jar" inside apps/libs folder like this.

[image]

[image]

**Step 6 :** : After doing all this, I am adding following line into the build.gradle file
     compile files 'libs/mylib.jar'

and then sync.

After Adding the Jar, I am calling its function inside Android App Function 
but in this case its showing me error "can not resolve the MyPackage", where as it shows me this inside the application scope

[image]

[image]

Now I could not proceed further in order to include and call jar files function.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: question is why didn't you use gradle's java plugin?

Comment: Can you verify that you can use this jar in any other plain java program?

Comment: @Yashasvi :  Yes i can use this jar in any other java program

Answer (score 0):

in your app>build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile files('libs/mylib.jar')   // add this
}
```

Comment: did you read the question? he wrote: *i am adding following line into build.gradle file compile files 'libs/mylib.jar'*

Comment: I have already added this line and then synced, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project structure-> modules->app->dependencies then check your jar is available or not. If your jar is not available then go to add icon on right top then add jar dependency.

Comment: I have done this also and added my jar as dependency into my projects.but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try Android Archive (AAR) file rather than Jar. This is very effective library type for android

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) for more info